# Send Email Extended SP2007 Workflow lookup field character limit?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm using the Send Email Extended functionality from the SharePoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities on Codeplex.  We have no issue sending the actual email, but there appears to be a 255 character limit on a lookup field in the body of the email.  Basically, we are pulling a description field from an InfoPath form into the email, but the text gets truncated.  When we check the form in the library it contains all of the text.  We need to be able to pull everything from the description field in the form.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Promote the Infopath field to a plain text multiline text field and then merge that into your email body. Also make sure the field is set to allow unlimited length in document libraries.

Comment: It is already a plain text multiline field, how do I merge that into the body?

Comment: Use the Add Lookup function from the email form. And added something else to check.

Comment: The lookup is already in the email.

Comment: The issue is when the form is sent, somewhere in the workflow process the lookup only pulls 255 characters, or it is somehow restricted to 255 characters.  The text box in the form has no limit.

Comment: What happens if you use the standard send email action? If that is fine, then it sounds like a defect in the codeplex project.

Comment: I can't use the standard email function, I need to be able to specify a sender.

Comment: It was suggested as a test. If the standard email action does not exhibit that behavior, then it is a defect with the codeplex feature and will need to be fixed.